# Breakpoints dont work in Monodroid multithreading applications

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, xamarin.android

When debugging multithreading application in monodroid when i make breakpoints after lock (...) or ONLY IF statement in code - it isn't works. But it work when i make breakpoint before that keywords and then in step by step debugging.  Why? How fix that?

Code (Sensor listener class):

```
static object lockAll = new object();
        public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent ev)
        {
            int g1 = 8; //Breakpoint in this place works
            lock (lockAll)
            {
             int g2 = 8; //Breakpoint in this place isn't works
            }
        }
```

Or:

```
    public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent ev)
    {
        Sensor curS = ev.Sensor;  //Breakpoint in this place works
        if (curS.Type == SensorType.Accelerometer)
            {
            int g2 = 8; //Breakpoint in this place isn't works
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same issue with with monodroid via the VS2010 IDE.  Often times I have to force-close the app on the tablet (or other device), close the IDE, re-open the IDE, do a re-deployment of the application.. and then *SOMETIMES* the breakpoints will start working as expected again.

Comment: That is other problem. When Visual studio can't delete debug file. I fix it downloaded software named "unloker"(http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) and using such bat file :@echo off
D:\MyProject\bin\UnlockerPortable\App\Unlocker\Unlocker.exe D:\MyProject\bin\Debug\Point.dll.mdb /S
del Debug\MyProject.dll.mdb /F /Q

:error
echo Failed with error #%errorlevel%.
exit /b 0                                                               then you can add this bat to exected autamaticaly in VS before build. This will fex this bug. But that is other bug